# Multiply listbox by combobox

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a ListBox `lstRoomType` that has 5 types of rooms, each with its own prices. And then I have a ComboBox (`cboNumberOfNights`) with the number of nights (from 1 to 31)

How can I multiply `lstRoomType` by `cboNumberOfNights` to get the room rate?

---

**Update**

The  entries in my listbox are a bunch of strings:

```
"room a $25"
"room b $30"
"room c $40"
```

I need to also extract the numeric value from the selected string.

Comment: You described the right way. Just do it.

Comment: juste like you said: multiply the `lstRoomType` to `cboNumberOfNights`

Comment: I'm having trouble on getting the values from the selected items in the listbox and combobox for me to multiply. How do I convert the inputs so that I can multiply them?

Comment: How to get data out of a `ListBox` or `ComboBox` control is something that you can easily research for yourself and is not related to multiplication.  It's done the same way regardless of what you intend to do with the data. For a start, have you read the documentation for those controls? Microsoft went to the trouble of explaining how those controls and every other type works and made that information easily accessible via the Help menu in VS. If you haven't availed yourself of that then it's too soon to be posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your `ListBox` and `ComboBox` are objects; in general, arbitrary objects cannot be multiplied by each other. In .NET, multiplication refers to the mathematical operation, which really only applies to a pair of numbers.<sup>1</sup>

What you are actually looking for is to multiply some value from the listbox, based on the listbox's currently selected item, by some value from the combobox, based on the combobox's currently selected item.

Both the WinForms [ListBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx) and the WPF [ListBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx) have a `SelectedItem` property, which you can use for this. Assuming you have some sort of type describing the room-type and price:

```
Public Class RoomType
    Property Description As String
    Property Price As Double
End Class
```

and you've populated your listbox with some collection of `RoomType`; and assuming you've populated your combobox with some collection of numbers, you can use:

```
Dim price = CType(lstRoomType.SelectedItem, RoomType).Price * CInt(cmbNumberOfNights.SelectedItem)
```

---

If the items of your listbox are not instances of some data type, but rather strings, then you'll have to parse the string returned by `SelectedItem`. Something like:

```
Dim roomRate = Double.Parse(CStr(lstRoomType.SelectedItem).Split(" ").Last().TrimStart("$"))
Dim price = roomRate * CInt(cmbNumberOfNights.SelectedItem)
```

Generally, it is far better that your items be objects with properties instead of strings; having to extract a number from the string is more error-prone.

---

<sup>1. Python allows you to multiply a string by a number: `s = 'abcd' * 5` and `s` will contain the string repeated 5 times. But this is only relevant for value types (and types such as `String`, which behave in many ways like value types), where multiple instances with the same value are equivalent; for reference types multiplication doesn't make much sense -- `lstRoomType * 5` could only return some collection with 5 references to the same listbox, which is pretty useless.</sup>

Comment: Yes.That exactly the question is. I'm using WinForms. My ComboBox items can be easily converted since They're number  (from 1 to 31)
But the listbox just contains types of rooms with their own prices.
I have Dimmed each type of the rooms and gave them values, just cant seem to assign them for each item so that I can multiply them to the cboBox

Comment: I populated the comboBox and able to get the value from its selectedItem. I just cant do the same with the listBox. 
I have 3 items there: "room a  $25", "room b $30", and "room c $40",
How can I set and get the value $25, $30, and $40 respectively based on the selected item?

Comment: @ChrisLaurie Updated my answer again. As I noted in the answer,it usually makes more sense that the items in the listbox should be instances of some data type, rather than strings.

Comment: @ChrisLaurie Your comment is like a patient coming to a doctor and saying "Something is wrong; you figure out what it is". What is the runtime error? At which line does it occur?

Comment: Well you did give him a solution precoded instead asking him to understand how forms and control work ^^

Comment: @Zev 
Lol. I'm sorry. It's the frustation. Been working on this project for 8 hrs so far.
It's at the end of this:
Dim roomRate = Double.Parse(CStr(lstRoomSelection.SelectedItem).Split(" ").Last().TrimStart('$'))

It says expression expected

Comment: @Mederic _how forms and controls work_ Or more precisely, why it doesn't make sense to try and multiply two arbitrary objects together. Which is what I wrote in the first two paragraphs of my answer. And I would suggest that being able to recognize and report the error information provided by the compiler or the runtime is a more important skill than _just_ understanding how forms and controls work.

Comment: I understand I just meant don't expect him to do debug and give you concrete details when he probbly just copy pasted the code since he didnt understand how to get the value of a listbox and that is basics of basics

Comment: @ChrisLaurie No need to apologize (and I'm sorry if you came away with that impression); just something you might want to keep in mind. Also, the problem was in the code that I wrote -- I was using `'` instead of `"` (too much context-switching between Python, C# and VB.NET) . I've fixed it, and it should work now.

Comment: @Zev It's a very smart way to split the Selected.Item. I never would've thought that. It still gives me a runtime error: 
+  $exception {"Input string was not in a correct format."} System.FormatException

Comment: My initial thought was assigning value to each index in the listBox. Just doesnt seem working so far.

Comment: @ChrisLaurie It sounds like the string which ends up being passed to `Double.Parse` cannot be parsed. If you put a breakpoint at `Dim roomRate = ... ` and enter `CStr(lstRoomType.SelectedItem).Split(" ").Last().TrimStart("$")` into the Watch pane or the Immediate pane, what do you get?

Comment: @Zev Aaah...you know what, it's because some extra space that I put before the $. So I had "Room A       $25 " instead of "Room A $25"
It works now. Much obliged, sir!

Comment: @ChrisLaurie As I said _having to extract a number from the string is more error-prone_, because you have to know the precise format of the string ahead of time.